# I want to communicate via http, but it changes to https

Tags: nginx, cakephp, amazon-ec2, https, centos7

It is a site that does not have an SSL certificate and can only communicate with http, but when $ this-> redirect (controller, action) is run with the contents of cakephp3.8, the connection is disconnected because it tries to transition with https. I will end up.

I can't consider whether cakephp is bad, aws (ec2) where the environment is placed is bad, or the web server (nginx + php-fpm) is bad. Can you give me some advice on what you think is suspicious?

environment
・ Cakephp 3.8
・ EC2 (centos7 nginx + php-fpm) No load balancer, no SSL certificate

Comment: first check ec2 and ngnix settings like https://blog.cloudboost.io/setting-up-an-https-sever-with-node-amazon-ec2-nginx-and-lets-encrypt-46f869159469

Comment: Do you have an https-rewrite in your vhost.conf in Nginx ?

Comment: you need to show us the configs in order to help you.. for example, make sure there is no force permanent/temporary redirects in the server block that is for port 80 in the nginx conf or you have something in the application itself for forcing the redirection.. try printing a string in the index.php before any other scripts. if that loads with http, you can be sure that it's related to server conf and not related to the code